# Delay while using tcpdump on Android - why?

Tags: java, android, tcpdump

I have written an Android application which starts tcpdump in a Process using ProcessBuilder.
When I start the process and poll on the InputStream, then it SOMETIMES happens, that the first output is written after 20-30 secs - although packets have been captured. 
I use tcpdump -l so output is linebuffered.
When I do some restarts on the process (killall) then it responds immediately on new packets.

Anyone any suggestions?
Is there any buffering on the network stack which has to be cleared first?

Thanks for any suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe try tcpdump -n so it doesn't try to resolve ip's to hostnames?

On the reruns, the lookups may be locally cached so it runs faster.